# Check if list of id's exists in table but with different group

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, and a list of itemId's

```
Variable Item Ids: [2,40,41,50,53]


**parent_table**

*id | title | amount*
1  | Test1 | 2
2  | Test2 | 1
```

This parent table sets the title of the composition and how many of a single itemId it needs, amount will always be 1 if groupId not is (NULL).

```
**composition_table**

*id | parentId | itemId | groupId*
1  | 1        | 2      | (NULL)  
2  | 2        | 40     | 1
3  | 2        | 41     | 1
4  | 2        | 50     | 2
5  | 2        | 51     | 2
6  | 2        | 53     | 2
```

So my mission here is to check, if my list of itemId's can combine with some of the relations in composition_table.

A valid combination of itemId's could be: [40,51], [40,50] or [41,50] etc.
A invalid combination of itemId's could be: [40,41], [50,51] or [40]

The combination has to have a itemId from every group. Invalid combination is ignored, no actions. For every combination, parent_table.id should be selected for output.

I hope there is a solution for one or more sql queries. I have tried a lot, but Im strugling with the distinct group part.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT
  pt.id
FROM
  parent_table pt
WHERE
  pt.amount = 1
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      composition_table ct
    WHERE
      ct.parentId = pt.id
      AND ct.itemId IN (2,40,41,50,53)
      AND ct.groupId IN (
        SELECT
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(ct.groupId))
        FROM
          composition_table ct
        WHERE
          ct.parentId = pt.id
      )
  )
```

As you can see, I cant figure out how I check that the combination only outputs if the groups is different.

I hope this is understandable and there is help out there, thanks in advance!

EDIT: Example of an result I am trying to get

array of parent_table.id

```
array (
 1, 2, 2
)
```

There is two combinations in the item ids [40,50] and [41,53], notice that when a item id is used in a combination, it cannot be used again.

So output will be Ids of the parent_table, if there exists valid relations in composition_table.

Comment: Hm, what is the result you're trying to get? Could you give an actual desired result for the data you're showing?

Comment: i made a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dedc)

Comment: Also, where's `dealId` coming from? :)

Comment: I have added kind of a explanation for the result, did it help?

Comment: How does 53 show up when it's not in the composition_table?

Comment: Its not, my mistake.. :-) edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not quite sure I'm understanding the NULL logic correctly, but this is what I came up with as a start;

```
SELECT parentid, MIN(a) numgroups
FROM (
  SELECT g.parentid, g.groupid, COUNT(ct.itemid) a
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT parentid, COALESCE(groupid, 0) groupid 
    FROM composition_table
  ) g 
  LEFT JOIN composition_table ct
    ON g.parentid = ct.parentid
   AND g.groupid  = COALESCE(ct.groupid, 0)
   AND ct.itemid IN (2, 40, 41, 52, 53)
  GROUP BY g.parentid, g.groupid
) z
GROUP BY parentid
```

It gives the result;

```
parentid    numgroups
1           1
2           2
```

([SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6d0e/1))

...which means 1 group in parent 1, 2 in parent 2, matching your example.

If you need the array with [1,2,2], just add the parent `numgroups` times when reading from the database.